# Shounen supernatural manga brothers who are able to kill spirits and are looking for their parents' killer

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am trying to find a shonen supernatural manga which is based on brothers who are able to kill spirits and are looking for their parents' killer. From what I remember, the brothers learn their martial arts through comic books and have a large tree in their home through which they travel to another realm. The main villain is a character who wears glasses/goggles and has three vertical scars across his lips.

The other character is a girl who has a guardian spirit shackled within her and comes out to save her when she is about to be hit by a bus.
The story then continues in another realm where they meet people who control similar guardian spirits and among them, one has the monkey king as his spirit partner.